# The query requires an index but I already have

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having this error:

```
[FirebaseError: The query requires an index {
  code: 'failed-precondition',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function]
}
```

But I already created this:
[image]

And my query is:

```
const q = query(videoRef, where("terms", "array-contains", term), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I think the "terms" field needs to be "Arrays" not "Descending" in your index

Comment: Thanks so much.. this was my problem.. I fixed e now it's working as expected!!

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem..

As @ grimsteel said, my index was supposed to be `Arrays` and not `Descending`.

After fixing this, it's working as expected!